# Global Variable inside Change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use variable value of **change function** outside it . I declared the variable outside **change function** , but still it outputs undefined value when i use it in other function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = "";
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (ischecked) {
            test = $(this).attr('class');
        }
        $('.first').text(test);
    });
    $('.second').text(test);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="all" value="Car">All
<input type="checkbox" class="got" value="Car">Game of Thrones
<input type="checkbox" class="bb" value="Car">Breaking Bad
<input type="checkbox" class="arrow" value="Car">Arrow

<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

In the `#second` div the variable value is undefined.

Comment: `test` is set to `""` when you set it as the text of `#second`. You don't give it a value until after you check the first checkbox. What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: That's because the value of `test` is set after checkbox is checked. and you're accessing it before value is set

Comment: okay !! i am learning , so how can i print the value in  second div.

Comment: just put it under `$('.first').text(test);`, in the change handler too.

Comment: Moving the statement `$('.second').text(test);` inside event handler will work

Comment: I wrote second div  outside the function just for example , I know i can move it in the function , but i want to get the input class if checkbox is checked , and use it in other function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` value will be assigned to `test` variable only on change of the input. But you are setting the text of `second` on `document ready` & at that time it is empty string.

There are numerous way to resolve this issue. You can put  `$('.second').text(test);` inside change function along with `$('.first').text(test);` or just create a function,call it on change of input & pass the `class` value as an argument.

Below is demo with a `function`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var test = "";
        $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
            var ischecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (ischecked) {
                test = $(this).attr('class');
            }
            $('.first').text(test);
    _setSecondDiv(test)
        });
        function _setSecondDiv(selClass){
        $('.second').text(test);
     }
    })
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3146nxLx/7/)

With multiple jQuery selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = "";
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (ischecked) {
            test = $(this).attr('class');
        }
        $('.first, .second').text(test); // Changed here

    });
})
```

[Working Example with multiple selector](https://jsfiddle.net/3146nxLx/8/)

Comment: Perfect, some people can help without criticizing :) thanks a lot !!